# How can i remove an group result sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query but it gives me more results that I want. For example when I run the query I will get 20 results from 2 products. Each product has a `group by` and the `group by` of the g.linkedline must be ignored and not shown in the results.

This is the query that I have

I tried to make a `select` over my `select`. I also tried a `TOP 1` but it gives me 1 result.

```
    SELECT i.itemcode, 
       g.warehouse, 
       Sum(g.aantal) AS Voorraad, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified 
             ELSE NULL 
           END)      AS LastDate 
FROM   dbo.gbkmut AS g 
       INNER JOIN dbo.items AS i 
               ON g.artcode = i.itemcode 
                  AND g.reknr = i.glaccountdistribution 
                  AND ( g.transtype = 'N' 
                         OR ( g.transtype = 'B' 
                              AND g.transsubtype = 'B' 
                              AND g.freefield1 NOT IN ( 'B', 'Q', 'W', 'K' ) 
                              AND g.blockitem = '0' 
                              AND g.allocationtype = 'F' ) 
                         OR ( g.transtype = 'B' 
                              AND g.transsubtype = 'B' 
                              AND g.freefield1 = 'V' 
                              AND g.allocationtype = 'B' ) ) 
WHERE  g.transtype = 'N' 
       AND ( i.itemcode = 'TESTARTIKEL' 
              OR i.itemcode = 'IQ7-60-2-INT' ) 
GROUP  BY i.itemcode, 
          g.warehouse, 
          g.linkedline
```

Comment: Remove it from group by. Also note that, you shouldn't use SUM() with a join that is many-to-many.

Comment: Will be very hard to answer without some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try it like this, you can use the window function row_number to force a ranking. If you are interested in only 1 thing per unique item code or where house, the nyou substitute the thing of interest in the Partition by clause and then specify what you want to order on in the order by clause. For example in the query below the item of interest is the ItemCode and we are ordering on the warehouse and aantal desc (which I'm assuming you want to see items with more aantal than less, but you can remove desc if you that suits your needs.

```
select * from
(
SELECT row_number()over(partition by i.Itemcode order by g.warehouse, g.aantal desc) as rowno, i.ItemCode, g.warehouse, SUM(g.aantal) AS Voorraad, MAX(CASE WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified ELSE NULL END) AS LastDate
FROM    dbo.gbkmut AS g INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
        ON g.artcode = i.ItemCode AND g.reknr = i.GLAccountDistribution AND (
                                                g.transtype = 'N' OR
                                                (g.transtype = 'B' AND 
                                                g.transsubtype = 'B' AND 
                                                g.freefield1 NOT IN ('B', 'Q', 'W', 'K') AND 
                                                g.BlockItem = '0' AND 
                                                g.AllocationType = 'F') OR ( g.transtype = 'B' AND g.transsubtype = 'B' AND g.freefield1 = 'V' AND g.AllocationType = 'B'))
WHERE g.transtype = 'N' AND (i.ItemCode = 'TESTARTIKEL' OR i.ItemCode = 'IQ7-60-2-INT') GROUP BY i.ItemCode, g.warehouse, g.LinkedLine 
) x where rowno=1;
```

Comment: If there are multiple rows in the result, which one is the correct one? Why would you get the first one ordered by some criteria?

Comment: In this scenario it is up to the OP to decide the priority on ordering. It's simply a method of finding the most significant thing of a set of groups and returning all of those groups.

Comment: Thank you @DwightReynoldson. but i get a error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '.'. and it looks like something in "desc) i.ItemCode"

Comment: Sorry @redouan I missed a comma out and didn't give the ranked column an alias. That should at least run now.

Comment: @DwightReynoldson it works but the result is not correct. 1 has good result and the other isnt correct

Comment: It will be the order by clause that needs altering. What isnit about the item that is priority? I.e. is it the date, is it the amount etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.ItemCode, g.warehouse, SUM(g.aantal) AS Voorraad, 
MAX(CASE WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified ELSE NULL END) AS LastDate
FROM    dbo.gbkmut AS g INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
    ON g.artcode = i.ItemCode AND g.reknr = i.GLAccountDistribution AND (
                                            g.transtype = 'N' OR
                                            (g.transtype = 'B' AND 
                                            g.transsubtype = 'B' AND 
                                            g.freefield1 NOT IN ('B', 'Q', 'W', 'K') AND 
                                            g.BlockItem = '0' AND 
                                            g.AllocationType = 'F') OR ( g.transtype = 'B' AND g.transsubtype = 'B' AND g.freefield1 = 'V' AND g.AllocationType = 'B'))
WHERE g.transtype = 'N' AND i.ItemCode = 'IQ7-60-2-INT' GROUP BY i.ItemCode, g.warehouse, g.LinkedLine
```

This returns results first Voorraad 0 and with the script of DwightReynoldson it returns 1080

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. thank you all!

There was a desc to the Voorraad thats is why the result wasn't correct.

This is the Code

```
select * from
(
SELECT 
    i.ItemCode, 
    g.warehouse, 
    SUM(g.aantal) AS Voorraad, 
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified 
        ELSE NULL 
    END) AS LastDate,
    row_number()
        over
            (partition by 
                i.Itemcode 
                order by 
                    g.warehouse 
                    ) as rowno
FROM    dbo.gbkmut AS g 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
        ON g.artcode = i.ItemCode 
            AND g.reknr = i.GLAccountDistribution 
            AND ( g.transtype = 'N' 
                    OR ( g.transtype = 'B' 
                          AND g.transsubtype = 'B' 
                          AND g.freefield1 NOT IN ( 'B', 'Q', 'W', 'K' ) 
                          AND g.blockitem = '0' 
                          AND g.allocationtype = 'F' ) 
                     OR ( g.transtype = 'B' 
                          AND g.transsubtype = 'B' 
                          AND g.freefield1 = 'V' 
                          AND g.allocationtype = 'B' ) ) 
WHERE  g.transtype = 'N' 
       AND ( i.itemcode = 'TESTARTIKEL' 
              OR i.itemcode = 'IQ7-60-2-INT' ) 
GROUP  BY i.itemcode, 
          g.warehouse, 
          g.linkedline
) x where rowno=1 ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
select *****Here the columns that you want to use****** from (****Your query****) anyName
```

In your case:

```
select *****Here the columns that you want to use****** from (
SELECT i.ItemCode, g.warehouse, SUM(g.aantal) AS Voorraad, MAX(CASE WHEN g.transtype = 'N' THEN g.sysmodified ELSE NULL END) AS LastDate
FROM    dbo.gbkmut AS g INNER JOIN  dbo.Items AS i
        ON g.artcode = i.ItemCode AND g.reknr = i.GLAccountDistribution AND (
                                                g.transtype = 'N' OR
                                                (g.transtype = 'B' AND 
                                                g.transsubtype = 'B' AND 
                                                g.freefield1 NOT IN ('B', 'Q', 'W', 'K') AND 
                                                g.BlockItem = '0' AND 
                                                g.AllocationType = 'F') OR ( g.transtype = 'B' AND g.transsubtype = 'B' AND g.freefield1 = 'V' AND g.AllocationType = 'B'))
WHERE g.transtype = 'N' AND (i.ItemCode = 'TESTARTIKEL' OR i.ItemCode = 'IQ7-60-2-INT') GROUP BY i.ItemCode, g.warehouse, g.LinkedLine 

) Name
```

Comment: Hi @pablo Lopez i tried that before and still i get the same results.

Comment: I understand this: In your group by, you need to add g.LinkedLine but in your final table this column should not appear, isn't it?